# Laravel, it's possible work with migrations on existing database?

Tags: php, database, laravel, migration

I'm building my first application using Laravel 4 but before know the migrations.

I created a database for that and I want to know if it's possible works migrations with my database.

Regards!

Comment: Yes it is. I had a similar requirement and found the following link on the Laravel forum to be useful. http://forums.laravel.io/viewtopic.php?id=8631 That discussion led me to this: https://github.com/barryvdh/laravel-migration-generator

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it's possible. Laravel online migration file generator made the task easy. Just enter your existing table schema and get Laravel migration file.

Try: https://laravelarticle.com/laravel-migration-generator-online
[image]